# Why the given radius to Circleavatar inside a container widget is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, containers

[image]Here is my code..

```
  Container(
           width: 400,
           height: 250,
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             gradient:LinearGradient(
               colors: <Color>[
                 Colors.purpleAccent,
                 Colors.pink,
               ]
             ),
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
           ),
           child: CircleAvatar(
             backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/images.jpg'),
              radius: 1,
           ),
         ),
```

Above in the code the radius i given is 1 but it is not working instead the image is taking the full size as the given height to container.

Here is the output image and here the radius given to image is 1 but still it taking the whole container space.

Comment: Your code is working correct what do you exact want

Comment: Yes, it is working properly. Can you show your output image?

Comment: I have provided the output image, plz refer to that @ChiragBargoojar

Comment: I wanted a small radius image at the top . @RavindraS.Patil

Comment: @Peaveen Kumar You want to display this image on whole container?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil  No sir I wanted a small size according to given radius but the image radius is not coming according to my given radius in circleavatar , it taking the whole height of container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your `CircleAvatar` with a `Center` widget to see if it is constrained:

```dart
Container(
        width: 400,
        height: 250,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: <Color>[
            Colors.purpleAccent,
            Colors.pink,
          ]),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage(
              'images/images.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            radius: 5,
          ),
        ),
      )
```